# R - Multiple chi square test on dataframe per row - get results same dataframe

Tags: r, row, chi-squared

I'm interested in performing chi-square test of group 1 x group2 (per gene/row) and group1 x group3 (per gene/row) and get the p-value and residuals in the same data frame. Creating columns for each comparison.

```
Genes<-c("GENE_A", "GENE_B","GENE_C")
Group1_Mut<-c(20,10,5)
Group1_WT<-c(40,50,55)
Group2_Mut<-c(10, 30, 10)
Group2_WT<-c(80, 60, 80)
Group3_Mut <- c(10,15,30)
Group3_WT <- c(30,40,45)
main<-data.frame(Genes,Group1_Mut,Group1_WT,Group2_Mut,Group2_WT, Group3_Mut,Group3_WT)
```

First I tried the example I found here at stackoverflow (but just for two groups comparations)

```
library(dplyr)

main %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(
  chisq.statistic = chisq.test(matrix(c(Group1_Mut, Group1_WT, Group2_Mut, Group2_WT), 
nrow = 2))$statistic
)
```

The chi-square value doesn´t match another statistics program

I tried again for just two groups:

```
main2 <- select(main,c(Group1_Mut, Group1_WT, Group2_Mut, Group2_WT))
main2 %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate (statistics = chisq.test(main2))
```

but got this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `statistics`.
i `statistics = chisq.test(main2)`.
x `statistics` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
i Did you mean: `statistics = list(chisq.test(main2))` ?
i The error occurred in row 1.
```

Then tried this:

```
 main2 %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate (statistics = list(chisq.test(main2)))
```

got:

```
  Group1_Mut Group1_WT Group2_Mut Group2_WT statistics
       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <list>    
1         20        40         10        80 <htest>   
2         10        50         30        60 <htest>   
3          5        55         10        80 <htest>
```

Any ideas on how can I do this test? Is there any functions that perform Chi-square on multiple comparisons?

Comment: What's wrong with the last code block? I can't tell exactly what you're trying to compare to what, since you have two columns per group. It might partly be a data management issue—reshaping might help to get a better alignment of what you're actually trying to compare. You also might want to use the [many models approach](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) or some of the [tidymodels](https://tidymodels.tidymodels.org/) tools

Comment: Thanks, Camille. I want to do chisquare test comparing frequencies of groups (1 and 2). One test per gene/row. 
the last code block , I didn´t get the statistics on the dataframe.  The first code block returned statistics value on the dataframe, but, I guess it was not correctly.

Comment: So if you've got a list of the test objects you're interested in, you could use something like `broom::glance` or `broom::tidy` to extract the statistics, or do it manually. In that last block, are those the tests you want, or you're also still trying to get the tests setup right?